# Pyglet loading image

Tags: python, pyglet

I had a pyglet code where I loaded the spaceship image. It showed me this (with a black background) :

[image: original spaceship image]

After about 5 months without ever touching the code, I just compiled it and I get this instead:

[image: new spaceship image]

The same remark is true with all other images: I have these green lines & the image is blurred. Any idea if something has changed with Pyglet loading image? I didn't find anything new in their docs.

My pyglet version is 1.5.7. The code is :

```
import pyglet

class GamewWindow(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        #background
        image = pyglet.image.load('spaceship.png')
        self.player = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(image,x=500,y=200)

    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()
        self.player.draw()

    def update(self,dt):
        pass

if __name__== "__main__":
    window = GamewWindow(1000,500,"Space Inv", resizable=False)
    pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(window.update,1/60)
    pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: The issue is not reproducible for me (with Pyglet 1.5.7). Ensure that the graphics driver is  up to date.

Comment: I actually tried it on an other PC and it worked. The graphic driver is up to date.

Comment: Which OS are you on? Windows? Does it help if you do `pyglet.resource.image('spaceship.png')`?

Comment: I'm on Windows, and it doesn't change anything